# Combinations of bit strings of length 9

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many bit strings of length $9$ contain exactly three $1s$? $10*10*10*9^6=531441000$ But then those first $1's$ don't necessarily have to be the first 3 digits. They can be elsewhere in the digit string as well.

At most three $1's$?

At least three $1's$?

Comment: $$1.)\binom{9}{3}$$
$$2.)\binom{9}{0}+\binom{9}{1}+\binom{9}{2}+\binom{9}{3}$$
$$3.)\text{ } 512-\binom{9}{0}-\binom{9}{1}-\binom{9}{2}$$

Comment: @Ethan at least three includes when thre are three. I don't like to give the op the answer right away, especially with homework-like questions like this one. It is better to first make them *suffer* :)

Comment: @chubakueno I thought by writing out the coefficients he would get the idea. I fixed the third one though.

Comment: Haha much thanks guys. Even just giving the answers helps out more than you think! I feel examples are the best way to learn.

Answer (score 2):

1. Exactly 3 ones: Select the positions for the 3 ones among 9, i.e., $\binom{9}{3}$
2. At most 3 ones: Same as above, but added up for 0, 1, 2, 3 ones, i.e., $\binom{9}{0}  + \binom{9}{1} + \binom{9}{2} + \binom{9}{3}$
3. At least 3 ones is easiest to compute as (all) - (at most 2 ones), i.e., $2^9 - \binom{9}{0} - \binom{9}{1} - \binom{9}{2}$